# How to toggle dark mode on and invert colors using Automator

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I am using Automator for the first time and I wonder if it possible to create a quick action to toggle dark mode on and invert colors using a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about invert colors, but to quickly toggle Dark/Light Mode, In Automator:

1. Make a new Application document:

[image]

2. Simply add the chunk for `Change System Appearance > Toggle Light/Dark`:

[image]

3. Save and name the application somewhere you can easily activate it, such as the Desktop so you can double-click it to toggle Dark Mode. Alternatively, you can simply search for it in Spotlight search and hit `Enter` to activate it.

I'll also plug a great app I came across called [Night Owl](https://nightowl.kramser.xyz), which is a menu bar app that toggles Dark Mode and you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it. This is what I use now after previously using the Automator solution.

Answer (score 0):

To create the quick action:

1. Open Automator.
2. Click File > New > Quick Action > Choose.
3. Double-click Change System Appearance.
4. Click File > Save. Name it Toggle System Appearance.

To assign a keyboard shortcut:

1. Open System Preferences.
2. Go to Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.
3. At the bottom will be Toggle System Appearance. Ensure it is checked and assign it a shortcut.